# GRUB bootloader gone after `bootrec.exe /FixMbr`

Tags: linux, windows, boot, grub, bootloader

My computer had GRUB bootloader installed with windows and kali linux.
I had problems booting into windows 10 and i had to execute these two commands:
`bootrec.exe /FixMbr` and `bootrec.exe /FixBoot` I rebooted my machine and everything worked fine.. except that GRUB bootloader was missing and now the machine boots directly in windows 10 and I can't boot in kali linux. How can I restore GRUB bootloader without losing any data?

(sorry for my english and the not so clear question, edits are well accepted)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run that command it set Windows Boot Manager as the default. You cannot boot into Linux from the Windows Boot Manager, as it will not support `ext?` type file systems nor can it understand (if so) to start them.

Quickway (may or may not work):

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\kali\grubx64.efi
```

More likely to work and probably easier if you are uncomfortable with CMD line. Look at [this youtube video](https://youtu.be/KLj2yQPWZDk?t=9m0s) and skip to 9:00 for editing the Boot Configuration Data.

To fix your issue you may have to use an ISO to boot into a RAM loaded Linux OS. Then you should run these as mentioned in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/209919/how-to-use-grub-as-default-bootloader-while-dual-booting-win7ubuntu#):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
sudo boot-repair
```

> and use "Recommended repair".GRUB2 will automatically detect windows
>   boot Path.

Good Luck!